# Materialize parallax scrolling resize in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am having issues with my `.parallax` CSS class that is done default by the framework it's not resizing like my main image when it comes to mobile view. It works well with a desktop view. They move more to the left the last two images is there a possibility to move them more center? I tried to center them using `position: no-repeat fixed center;` in CSS or using frameworks default parameters. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3wW7.jpg

The image goes off to the left and does not center.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parallax').parallax();
});
```

```css
.ha-bg-parallax {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/YqK1Oeu.jpg) no-repeat fixed center;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.parallax{
  position: no-repeat fixed center;
  max-width:100%;
}

.ha-bg-parallax .ha-parallax-body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav class="blue darken-1">
  
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="ha-bg-parallax text-center block-marginb-none" data-speed="20" data-type="background">
  <div class="ha-parallax-body">
    <div class="section scrollspy row title" id="home">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="section light-blue lighten-5">
  <div class="row container">
    <div class="section scrollspy" id="info">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax-container">
  <div class="parallax"><img alt="header1" src="https://i.imgur.com/QFPutVs.jpg"></div>
</div>
<div class="section light-blue lighten-5">
  <div class="section scrollspy" id="portfolio">
  </div>
  <!--row for parallax-->
</div>
<div class="parallax-container">
  <div class="parallax"><img alt="header2" src="https://i.imgur.com/gyYRcBK.jpg"></div>
</div>
<!--Floating Action Button custumize-->
<footer class="page-footer blue darken-1">
  <div class="col l4 offset-l2 s12 container center">
    <div class="section scrollspy" id="links">
    </div>
  </div>
```